# Use Bash to Read File Then Do "grep" with The Line Against The File Itself

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to read a file using Linux Bash and then use "grep" to run that line against the file itself. It seems not working to me...

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
while read line
do
    var1=$(grep $line $path)
    echo $?
    exit
done < $path
```

The $? returns 1. What's going on here?

Comment: You must quote things correctly. ``var1=$(grep "$line" "$path")`` and ``done < "$path"``

Comment: Use: `var1=$(grep -F "$line" "$path")`

Comment: nah, that's not the problem...

Comment: Thanks, anubhava, your solution works for me. I meant Aleks' solution doesn't work. I think $line doesn't contain newline character...

Comment: Alright I posted that as answer for future visitors, mark it accepted whenever you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -F` (fixed string) instead:

```
var1=$(grep -F "$line" "$path")
```